# How to convert a QByteArray in little endian format to a unsigned long

Tags: c++, qt, endianness, qbytearray, ulong

I have a QByteArray with 4 values in little endian format

```
QByteArray ba;
ba.append(0xbb);
ba.append(0x1c);
ba.append(0x51);
ba.append(0x1e);
```

to convert ba to big endian I do the following :

```
baBigEndian[0] = ba[3];
baBigEndian[1] = ba[2];
baBigEndian[2] = ba[1];
baBigEndian[3] = ba[0];
```

to convert the big endian array to an unsigned long i tried the following:

```
baBigEndian.toULong(&ok,10);
```

The little endian byte array is correctly converted to big endian but the .toULong returns 0 in stead of 508632251.

How can I convert the baBigEndian array to an unsigned long? Or is there a way to directly convert from a little endian array to an unsigned long?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want this code to work on all CPUs (both big-endian ones and little-endian ones) ?

Comment: I get the bytes of the byte array over a serial connection so I am not sure if it matters(probably all CPUs just to be safe)

Comment: It does matter, because e.g. a PowerPC CPU will want to see those bytes in a different order than e.g. an Intel CPU.  That said, the `ntohl()` function (as seen in my answer below) will handle that issue correctly in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `memcpy`

```
quint32 value = 0; //or qint32
memcpy(&value, baBigEndian.data(), sizeof(quint32));//or baBigEndian instead baBigEndian.data() if you use plain array instead QByteArray
```

Also, it can be done with `reinterpret_cast` but I do not recommend you to use `reinterpret_cast` because I had some problems on `arm` processors (while on `x86` it works fine).

Comment: Reinterpret_cast won't work on little-endian architectures.  Most architectures these days are little-endian.

Comment: Using memcpy like you illustrated returns 3139195166 instead of 508632251

Comment: 508632251 is 0x1e511cbb (variable `ba`) and 3139195166 is 0xBB1C511E (variable `baBigEndian`). So in my example replace `baBigEndian` with `ba`. I don't know what variable exactly you want to convert

Answer (score 0):

`toULong()` won't work, since it expects the QByteArray to contain a string representation of the number in ASCII format (e.g. `"0xbb1c511e"`, which is 10 ASCII bytes), and your QByteArray contains the literal binary bytes instead (e.g. `0xbb1c511e`, which is 4 binary bytes).

Assuming your QByteArray contains the four bytes in big-endian format (as it does after step 2 in your example code), then this would work:

```
unsigned long val = ntohl(*((const unsigned long *)ba.data()));
```

Note however that `sizeof(unsigned long)` is not guaranteed to be 4 bytes on all platforms, so you'd be better off using a fixed-width type that is guaranteed to always be 4 bytes wide instead, e.g.

```
quint32 val = ntohl(*((const quint32 *)ba.data()));
```

Comment: What should I #include to be able to use ntohl()